# Power Apps wrap into Android apk and sharepoint data fetching issue

Tags: canvas, apk, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-selected-items

I had convert power apps canvas application to android apk through power apps wrap feature. While converting I had given api permission to SharePoint sites in Azure AD and when I am signing in my apk it shows error from token exchange permission denied due missing connection ACL.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this command in PowerShell on your desktop as administrator.

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.Powershell
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerApps.PowerShell -AllowClobber
Add-PowerAppsAccount
Add-AdminAllowedThirdPartyApps -ApplicationID "YOURAPPID"
```